# Writing a simple microsoft graph client without using a web server

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, office365-restapi

I'm looking to write a script to update a Distribution List in Office365. I'm in the process of learning the MS Graph API and have gotten the python REST sample to work. It appears that all the sample Graph API code, regardless of language or platform, has an assumption that I'm coding from a web user interface in one way or another.

Is it possible to write a simple client that runs from a Linux box and allows me to specify my Office 365 id in my code, without having to select it from a browser? My goal is to have this run as a cron job which updates the Distribution List nightly. Python is not a requirement, it's just where I chose to start in learning Graph.

Comment: Did you end up finding some way to do this? I am hitting the same wall in that it seems like you can't just have a user create an "app password" to use for RESTful interactions. It is not an option to set up a web server to handle requests and would rather plug in a key for pragmatic access (i.e. the way AWS authenticates with an access key and a secret access key)

Comment: No, I never did. My experience indicates that MS assumes you're running inside a browser and prompts you for a password. If you look at Eric's response to me, in the comments, he believes there is a way to do it. I had looked at the links he provided but it didn't help me resolve this. I eventually gave up on this.

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API is not restricted to web apps and can be used in native/desktop apps as well.  Essentially you have to start by registering your app to get your app ID, then use whatever REST APIs you want to implement the Auth Code Grant flow to get access.  When you first issue a request the user will be prompted to sign in with their Office 365 account to grant access to your app, and away you go.

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/get-started/rest

Comment: Perhaps I'm just dense, but... You say "When you first issue a request the user will be prompted to sign in with their Office 365 account." So I still need a web browser for me to confirm that I'm the user logging in. Is there a way that I can bypass a browser confirmation of who I am by specifying my login/password in code? I understand this is a very unsecure thing to do, but I need to run this from a cron job off hours, with no human interaction whatsoever.

Comment: You can, but I've never done it yet and it looks very complicated.  See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/laurelle/2016/02/12/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-and-office-365-api-in-a-service-or-in-a-windows-appuwp-without-a-graphical-interface/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api