# Is it possible to authenticate to Microsoft Graph without a server?

Tags: javascript, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to create an integration to OneDrive using the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/converged_auth). Our app is fully client-side, there's no moving parts on a server, so authentication has to be directly browser to Microsoft.

We have an existing integration with OneDrive that uses the older OneDrive API. That does permit client-flow authentication.

There is an example for AngularJS, but that turns out to require a NodeJS server and have a server-flow authentication, again. NodeJS authentication [requires a secret to be passed over](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-connect-rest-sample/blob/master/app.js#L66), which I obviously can't put in public JS.

I cannot find any examples of authenticating to the graph API without a secret, am I right in saying that client-flow authentication is not supported?

p.s. I have looked at [Writing a simple microsoft graph client without using a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003964/writing-a-simple-microsoft-graph-client-without-using-a-web-server), but this question seems to be asking whether it's possible to make API calls without user interaction, rather than what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your scenario correctly, you're looking for the [implicit grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit). I wrote a [blog post](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-implicit-grant/) on using this a while back that might also be helpful.